# iCalendar file with RRULE and EXDATE not imported properly through GMAIL

Tags: email, gmail, icalendar

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
PRODID:-//td//EN
VERSION:2.0
METHOD:REQUEST
BEGIN:VEVENT
LAST-MODIFIED:20161123T152155Z
DTSTART;TZID=America/Montreal:20170116T180000
DTEND;TZID=America/Montreal:20170116T190000
DTSTAMP:20161123T152155Z
ORGANIZER:mailTo:info@td.com
CREATED:20161123T152155Z
ATTENDEE:
DESCRIPTION:Initiation progam
LOCATION:7700 Boulevard Décarie, Montréal, QC H4P 2H4
SUMMARY:Initiation program
CATEGORIES:Initiation
CLASS:PUBLIC
UID:td.COM@Activity:1217920
SEQUENCE:0
RRULE:FREQ=WEEKLY;UNTIL=20170328T000000Z;BYDAY=MO
EXDATE;TZID=America/Montreal:20170306T180000
STATUS:CONFIRMED
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

I've got ths iCalendar invite which represents an event that should occur:  Weekly from 6pm to 7pm on Monday from Mon Jan 16, 2017 to Mon Mar 27, 2017 except Mon Mar 6, 2017 6pm (EST)

It works as expected when imported;

- in google calendar directly
- in outlook

but does not when added from a email in gmail.

Oddly enough, the preview of the email is correct but clicking on "Add to calendar" ignores the recurence rule.
[image: email snip]

Removing the EXDATE from the file makes the RRULE work perfectly but I can't seem to get it working with it.

Is theres something obvious I'm doing wrong with my event or should I treat this as an error from Gmail?

Answer (score 0):

Don't if it is related to your issue (maybe you edited it on purpose ?...) but you have an empty ATTENDEE property.

Comment: Yes, I edited that out on purpose. Having it does not fix the issue sadly.